# Google Wallet Integration through custom widget in Vaadin6

Tags: javascript, vaadin, jsni, android-pay, gwt-widgets

I need to integrate Google wallet into my Vaadin 6 application, downloaded wallet api/demo from [here](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/samples#iap-java).

First I was trying to run this given sample into vaadin but after a long effort I am stuck now. Tried lots of ways/examples , studied lot about widgets but only [this](http://java-liferay.blogspot.com/2013/01/how-to-wrap-javascript-libarary-in.html) example was found to be simple and working.

I added my lines of code, the process going smooth upto the **purchase()** call but when it calls wallet API function **buy()** the browser's page get cleared and nothing happened as if program ended.

Kindly suggest me any example or any work around if my approach is wrong.

Cheers

script.js

```
    function proceedMessage(message) {
    alert(message);
    return message;
}

function loadConfig(){
    google.load('payments', '1.0', {
        'packages': ['sandbox_config']
    });
}

var paymentStatus ;
//Success handler
var successHandler = function(status){
    if (window.console != undefined) {
        console.log("Purchase completed successfully: ", status);
        //window.location.reload();
    }
    paymentStatus = "SUCCESS";
}

//Failure handler
var failureHandler = function(status){
    if (window.console != undefined) {
        console.log("Purchase failed ", status);
    }
    paymentStatus = "FAILURE";
}

function result(){
    return paymentStatus;
}

function purchase(item) {
    var generated_jwt;
    if (item == "Item1") {
        generated_jwt = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiIxMjgyOTQzNjkwNDgwNzQ5NTkwMiIsImF1ZCI6Ikdvb2dsZSIsInR5cCI6Imdvb2dsZS9wYXltZW50cy9pbmFwcC9pdGVtL3YxIiwiaWF0IjoxMzg4MTM5NDQzLCJleHAiOjEzODgxMzk1MDMsInJlcXVlc3QiOnsibmFtZSI6IlBpZWNlIG9mIENha2UiLCJkZXNjcmlwdGlvbiI6IlZpcnR1YWwgY2hvY29sYXRlIGNha2UgdG8gZmlsbCB5b3VyIHZpcnR1YWwgdHVtbXkiLCJwcmljZSI6IjEwLjUwIiwiY3VycmVuY3lDb2RlIjoiVVNEIiwic2VsbGVyRGF0YSI6InVzZXJfaWQ6MTIyNDI0NSxvZmZlcl9jb2RlOjMwOTg1NzY5ODcsYWZmaWxpYXRlOmFrc2RmYm92dTlqIn19.k8OWXVdemtfNFPu4-PSc-1OIkPS7o0bYA1MMq1dhUXQ";
    }  else {
        return;
    }
        goog.payments.inapp.buy({
            'jwt'     : generated_jwt,
            'success' : successHandler,
            'failure' : failureHandler
        });
    }
```

---

client side component VGoogleWallet.java

```
package com.example.testing.client.ui;
import com.example.testing.client.ui.MessageJSNI;
import com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.client.ApplicationConnection;
import com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.client.Paintable;
import com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.client.UIDL;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Document;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
import com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Event;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;

/**
 * Client side widget which communicates with the server. Messages from the
 * server are shown as HTML and mouse clicks are sent to the server.
 */
public class VGoogleWallet extends Widget implements Paintable, ClickHandler {

    /** Set the CSS class name to allow styling. */
    public static final String CLASSNAME = "v-googlewallet";

    public static final String CLICK_EVENT_IDENTIFIER = "click";

    /** The client side widget identifier */
    protected String paintableId;

    /** Reference to the server connection object. */
    protected ApplicationConnection client;

    /**
     * The constructor should first call super() to initialize the component and
     * then handle any initialization relevant to Vaadin.
     */
    public VGoogleWallet() {
        // TODO This example code is extending the GWT Widget class so it must set a root element.
        // Change to a proper element or remove this line if extending another widget.

        setElement(Document.get().createDivElement());
        // This method call of the Paintable interface sets the component
        // style name in DOM tree"
        setStyleName(CLASSNAME);

    }

    /**
     * Called whenever an update is received from the server 
     */
    public void updateFromUIDL(UIDL uidl, ApplicationConnection client) {
        // This call should be made first. 
        // It handles sizes, captions, tooltips, etc. automatically.
        if (client.updateComponent(this, uidl, true)) {
            // If client.updateComponent returns true there has been no changes and we
            // do not need to update anything.
            return;
        }

        // Save reference to server connection object to be able to send
        // user interaction later
        this.client = client;

        // Save the client side identifier (paintable id) for the widget
        paintableId = uidl.getId();

        // Process attributes/variables from the server
        // The attribute names are the same as we used in 
        // paintContent on the server-side

        String message = uidl.getStringAttribute("message");
        String paymentStatus = uidl.getStringVariable("paymentStatus");
        getElement().setInnerHTML(MessageJSNI.proceedMessage(message));
        MessageJSNI.loadConfig();
        MessageJSNI.purchase();
        paymentStatus = MessageJSNI.getResult();

        client.updateVariable(paintableId, "paymentStatus", "PAID", true);
    }

}
```

---

server side component GoogleWallet.java

```
package com.example.testing;

import java.util.Map;

import com.vaadin.terminal.PaintException;
import com.vaadin.terminal.PaintTarget;
import com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent;

/**
 * Server side component for the VGoogleWallet widget.
 */
@com.vaadin.ui.ClientWidget(com.example.testing.client.ui.VGoogleWallet.class)
public class GoogleWallet extends AbstractComponent {

    private String message = "default message";
    private String paymentStatus ;

    public GoogleWallet(String message){
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintContent(PaintTarget target) throws PaintException {
        super.paintContent(target);

        // Paint any component specific content by setting attributes
        // These attributes can be read in updateFromUIDL in the widget
        target.addAttribute("message", message);
        target.addVariable(this, "paymentStatus", "UNPAID");

    }

//  /**
//   * Receive and handle events and other variable changes from the client.
//   * 
//   * {@inheritDoc}
//   */
    @Override
    public void changeVariables(Object source, Map<String, Object> variables) {
        super.changeVariables(source, variables);
//
//       Variable set by the widget are returned in the "variables" map.
//
        if (variables.containsKey("paymentStatus")) {
//
            // When the user has clicked the component we increase the 
            // click count, update the message and request a repaint so 
            // the changes are sent back to the client.
            paymentStatus = (String) variables.get("paymentStatus");
            System.out.println(paymentStatus);
            requestRepaint();
        }
    }

}
```

---

JavaScript Native Interface class MessageJSNI.java

```
package com.example.testing.client.ui;

public class MessageJSNI {

    protected MessageJSNI() {
    }

    public native static String proceedMessage(String message) /*-{
        return $wnd.proceedMessage(message);
    }-*/;

    public native static void loadConfig()/*-{
    $wnd.loadConfig();
  }-*/;

    public native static void purchase()/*-{
    $wnd.purchase('Item1');
  }-*/;


    public native static String getResult()/*-{
    return $wnd.result();
    }-*/;


}
```

---

TestingWidgetset.gwt.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 1.7.0//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.7.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module>
    <inherits name="com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.DefaultWidgetSet" />

    <script src="script.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 

    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <!--
     Uncomment the following to compile the widgetset for one browser only.
     This can reduce the GWT compilation time significantly when debugging.
     The line should be commented out before deployment to production
     environments.

     Multiple browsers can be specified for GWT 1.7 as a comma separated
     list. The supported user agents at the moment of writing were:
     ie6,ie8,gecko,gecko1_8,safari,opera

     The value gecko1_8 is used for Firefox 3 and later and safari is used for
     webkit based browsers including Google Chrome.
    -->
    <!-- <set-property name="user.agent" value="gecko1_8"/> -->

    <!--
     To enable SuperDevMode, uncomment this line and use the
     Super Dev Mode for Vaadin 6 add-on.

     SuperDevMode enables debugging of the client side of a Vaadin
     application using the JavaScript debugger of a browser. Java code is
     shown and debugging can take place on the Java level when using a browser
     that support source maps (currently Chrome, implementation under work
     for Firefox).

     See https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/super-dev-mode-for-vaadin-6 for
     more information and instructions.
    -->
    <!-- <set-configuration-property name="devModeRedirectEnabled" value="true" /> -->

</module>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some more hours at least I got this demo running in my Vaadin 6 app, although now I am getting some issue in my server generated JWT but this demo is working is now working.

Following are the changes in the code

script.js

```
function buy(){
    google.payments.inapp.buy({
    'jwt'     : "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiIxMDk3OTc5MTY0NTUxNTM4MDY2OSIsImF1ZCI6Ikdvb2dsZSIsInR5cCI6Imdvb2dsZS9wYXltZW50cy9pbmFwcC9pdGVtL3YxIiwiaWF0IjoxMzg4NDcwMzM5LCJleHAiOjEzODg0NzAzOTksInJlcXVlc3QiOnsibmFtZSI6IkNsb3VkU3RyZWFtMTUiLCJkZXNjcmlwdGlvbiI6IkNsb3VkU3RyZWFtIE9uZSBtb250aCBwYWNrYWdlIGZvciAxNSB1c2VycyIsInByaWNlIjoiMjUwLjAwIiwiY3VycmVuY3lDb2RlIjoiVVNEIiwic2VsbGVyRGF0YSI6InVzZXJfaWQ6MTIyNDI0NSxvZmZlcl9jb2RlOjMwOTg1NzY5ODcsYWZmaWxpYXRlOmFrc2RmYm92dTlqIn19.JoUUTcVilz8nBSPjbCVuESi-QUS7fN6f9PeEseE7CSY",
    'success' : function(status){if (window.console != undefined) {console.log("Purchase completed successfully: ", status);}},
    'failure' : function(status){if (window.console != undefined) {console.log("Purchase failed ", status);}}
});
}
```

---

client side widget VGoogleWallet.java

```
package com.example.testing.client.ui;

import com.example.testing.client.ui.MessageJSNI;
import com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.client.ApplicationConnection;
import com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.client.Paintable;
import com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.client.UIDL;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Document;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
import com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Event;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;

/**
 * Client side widget which communicates with the server. Messages from the
 * server are shown as HTML and mouse clicks are sent to the server.
 */
public class VGoogleWallet extends Widget implements Paintable, ClickHandler {

    /** Set the CSS class name to allow styling. */
    public static final String CLASSNAME = "v-googlewallet";

    /** The client side widget identifier */
    protected String paintableId;

    /** Reference to the server connection object. */
    protected ApplicationConnection client;

    /**
     * The constructor should first call super() to initialize the component and
     * then handle any initialization relevant to Vaadin.
     */
    public VGoogleWallet() {
        // TODO This example code is extending the GWT Widget class so it must set a root element.
        // Change to a proper element or remove this line if extending another widget.

        setElement(Document.get().createDivElement());
        // This method call of the Paintable interface sets the component
        // style name in DOM tree"
        setStyleName(CLASSNAME);

    }

    /**
     * Called whenever an update is received from the server 
     */
    public void updateFromUIDL(UIDL uidl, ApplicationConnection client) {
        // This call should be made first. 
        // It handles sizes, captions, tooltips, etc. automatically.
        if (client.updateComponent(this, uidl, true)) {
            // If client.updateComponent returns true there has been no changes and we
            // do not need to update anything.
            return;
        }

        // Save reference to server connection object to be able to send
        // user interaction later
        this.client = client;

        // Save the client side identifier (paintable id) for the widget
        paintableId = uidl.getId();

            MessageJSNI.buy();
    }


}
```

---

TestingWidgetset.gwt.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 1.7.0//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.7.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module>
    <inherits name="com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.DefaultWidgetSet" />

    <script src="script.js"></script>

    <script src="https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/inapp/lib/buy.js"></script> 
    <!--
     Uncomment the following to compile the widgetset for one browser only.
     This can reduce the GWT compilation time significantly when debugging.
     The line should be commented out before deployment to production
     environments.

     Multiple browsers can be specified for GWT 1.7 as a comma separated
     list. The supported user agents at the moment of writing were:
     ie6,ie8,gecko,gecko1_8,safari,opera

     The value gecko1_8 is used for Firefox 3 and later and safari is used for
     webkit based browsers including Google Chrome.
    -->
    <!-- <set-property name="user.agent" value="gecko1_8"/> -->

    <!--
     To enable SuperDevMode, uncomment this line and use the
     Super Dev Mode for Vaadin 6 add-on.

     SuperDevMode enables debugging of the client side of a Vaadin
     application using the JavaScript debugger of a browser. Java code is
     shown and debugging can take place on the Java level when using a browser
     that support source maps (currently Chrome, implementation under work
     for Firefox).

     See https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/super-dev-mode-for-vaadin-6 for
     more information and instructions.
    -->
    <!-- <set-configuration-property name="devModeRedirectEnabled" value="true" /> -->

</module>
```

---

MessageJSNI.java

```
package com.example.testing.client.ui;

public class MessageJSNI {

    protected MessageJSNI() {
    }

    public native static void buy()/*-{
    $wnd.buy();
  }-*/;

}
```