# How can I create Google Wallet Sandbox Account?

Tags: javascript, php, payment, jwt, android-pay

I am currently working on payment through google wallet. I have downloaded different sample codes but they are not working.

I want to know that how can I create google wallet sandbox account for buyer and seller so that I can further implement the functionality. And How can I get Merchant ID from google Wallet and all other credentials required for the integration of google wallet through PHP.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented wallet in my vaadin application after a lot of hardwork, here is a link to my question having my code also may be the script part can work for you to understand the flow [Google Wallet Integration through custom widget in Vaadin6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20855967/2842200)

and for your second question regarding merchant account credentials have a look at this page I got mine from here 
https://developers.google.com/wallet/dashboard ( this link is now redirecting to android pay which is not the case even 3 days before..sory for this )